# IE11 @font-face Issue

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-11, truetype, woff

I know there are hundred of questions about this, where IE11 isn't loading the custom fonts properly, or at all - but I've yet to come across an answer, or solution that has actually worked in my case.

I first started off by going to Font Squirrel and letting that do it's job. The weird thing there, is that if I open up the file on my computer, the font loads as it should in IE11, but as soon as I upload it to my server, it reverts to the fallback.

I have been using the IE Bulletproof technique, and THAT no longer works, all browsers load the font in fin, but IE11 simply refuses to cooperate.

I have separated the font-face calls into two separate listings, one with just the .EOT, the second with the .EOT?#iefix, .WOFF2, WOFF, .TTF and .SVG

I have tried the minified version, just calling the .WOFF and .WOFF2

...and I still cannot get this font to load in IE11.  Does anyone have any other possible solution that hasn't been previously listed on any of the other hundred questions about this issue?

**Specifics:**

I'm looking to load a font into my web page and have it display in IE11 (Version: 11.0.9600.18524IS)

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but IE11 is not running in compatibility mode, is it? That way, it would emulate IE5, which has no support for webfonts.

Comment: no, it is not. but thank you for asking.